# Sed string replace into file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Using Sed because of large files, I'd like to match strings of form

> '09/07/15 16:56:36,333000000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'

and replace it by

> '09/07/15 16:56:36','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS'

Checked by [regex tester](http://regexr.com/) this regex seems to match
`'\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{9}','DD\/MM\/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'`

but when I do

```
sed -ie "s#\(\x27\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\),\d{9}  
\(\x27,\x27DD\/MM\/RR HH24:MI:SS\)XFF\x27#\1\2\x27#g" inputfile
```

it does not replace anything.
What am I missing ?

Comment: Please note that `sed -ie` probably doesn't do what you want. `-i` actually takes an optional argument which it uses to create a backup of the file before modifying it. So in your case it will create `inputfilee`. If you didn't actually want to do a backup, I'd propose to change `sed -ie` to `sed -i -e` or even `sed -i` (`-e` is unnecessary if you provide only one expression at the command line).

Comment: I tried with only -i switch but it does not work either. Does the regex given seem right ?
I also tried with -r, but gave an error "invalid reference on s command".

Comment: That was just another, somewhat separate problem. It may cause some potentially unexpected results (new files being created), but doesn't concern the main problem — that's why I described it in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
s/,[[:digit:]]*//
s/XFF//
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked although [[:digit:]] did not seem to work.
Being on debian, I adapted to : 
`#!/bin/sed -f  
s/,[0-9]*//g  
s/XFF//g`

Comment: I must be tired, I tried again and [[:digit:]] works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: in the answer below I describe why your expression doesn't work in general. I would strongly suggest that you try to simplify your expression as much as possible first, or use @StevenPenny's excellent answer, because:

- applying the changes described below in your present expression would turn it into a hulking, unmaintainable regex nightmare;
- my remarks may not be exhaustive — they point out the cause, some of the particular problems, and sources for further investigation.

---

The problem is that `sed` and http://regexr.com/ regex engines are somewhat different. See the "RegEx engine" section on the website:

> While the core feature set of regular expressions is fairly consistent, different implementations (ex. Perl vs Java) may have different features or behaviours.
>
> RegExr uses your browser's RegExp engine for matching, and its syntax highlighting and documentation reflect the JavaScript RegExp standard.

Whereas the latest versions of GNU `sed` is mostly compatible with POSIX.2 Basic Regular Expressions (BREs). See the excerpt from the `sed(1)` manpage for GNU `sed`, version 4.2.2:

> **REGULAR EXPRESSIONS**
>
> POSIX.2 BREs should be supported, but they aren't completely because of performance problems.  The  \n  sequence  in  a  regular  expression matches the newline character, and similarly for \a, \t, and other sequences.

The descriptions of POSIX regex languages (that is BRE — Basic Regular Expressions and ERE — Extended Regular Expressions) are in the `regex(7)` manpage.

In particular, concerning your expression:

- Character class notation is different: for example, for digits you're using `\d`, while in BRE you should write `[[:digit:]]`; for white space, you're using `\s`, whereas in BRE there's `[[:space:]]`.
- Some characters have to be prepended with backslash in order to escape their literal meaning. That concerns `{`, which in BRE should be `\{`.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for the explanation. I'm new on both GNU sed tool and regular expressions. I was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721253/sed-regex-substitute) and  my very basic knowledge without thinking enough about different implementations.
Please, forgive my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: The POSIX regexes are hard to approach just by themselves. If you looked into `regex(7)`, you could see that the manpage authors themselves have a negative attitude towards having multiple kinds of regexes: "Having two kinds of REs is a botch".